# How to mock web api call in c#?

Tags: c#, mocking

I have two classes. FunctionalClass and WebApiClass

**FunctionalClass**

```
class FunctionalClass 
{

WebApiClass obj= new WebApiClass();

public void function1()
{

    obj.function1();

}

}
```

**WebApiClass**

```
public class WebApiClass
{


public void function1()
{

    if(someconditions is true)
    {
        WebApiCall();   
    }

}

public void WebApiCall()
{

    // Code for api call    

}
```

}

I want to mock WebApiCall(), how can I do that ?

Comment: Your provided code doesn't really have anything to do with your question. This is quite simply a 'research it for me' question. There are plenty of examples for mocking in C#

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you, how you can do it with [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page).
Here is simple test:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestMethodWasCalled()
{
    //Arrange
    var fakeWebApi = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<WebApiClass>(Members.CallOriginal);
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeWebApi.WebApiCall()).IgnoreCall();

    //Act
    FunctionalClass target = new FunctionalClass();
    target.function1();

    //Assert
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => fakeWebApi.WebApiCall());
}
```

By `var fakeWebApi = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<WebApiClass>(Members.CallOriginal);` we getting fake, which we can use to set up the behavior for all future instances of `WebApiClass`. It's important, because in `FunctionalClass` you creating new instance of it. When, we making a mock of WebApiCall by `Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeWebApi.WebApiCall()).IgnoreCall();`.

P.S. I changed the function1 in FunctionalClass to always call obj.function1().

Hope it helps!